# How extract code from project to gem fast (move class from project to gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubymine

I have a complex project written in Ruby on Rails. And i need to split it for smaller subrojects. And some code used in all subroject, so I want to move it to librabry (core) and after just reuse the library.

in .NET you could easily add project to your solution and project will be library type, then put classes to that project and compiler will compile dll and here it is - we have what we need. I need something ideologically the same but in Ruby.

How I could do that with the minimum eforts?

I'm using Rubymine 5

---

*The real question is only how to move classe to gem. Technically. I never done it before. So no decomposition and stuff like that. Only mechanism how to get class from project and put it to gem with easiest way.*

Comment: This heavily depends on your actual code base, how coupled your code is and what exactly needs to be shared. As such, there is no easy answer without knowing your code base. Still, when knowing your code base, the answer will apply very narrowly to it. These issues make your question rather unsuitable for StackOverflow. As a general advice, you should try to refactor your code to decouple it and define your API to connect the different parts later.

Comment: See my update, I think you understand me a little bit wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

I would suggest looking at popular gems and see how they do things. There's really not one right way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you need to include the gem in your `Gemfile`. For local development, you can reference it using something like

```
gem "mygem", :path => "path/to/gem/directory"
```

Then, you can simple move your classes to the gem and make sure they are required. Depending on your bundler setup, that might be done automatically. In your gem, you typically need to manually require your files.

You should have a look at one or more other gems which do similar things to yours for inspiration on how to structure it.